# There has been a critical error on your website

Tags: plugins, errors, updates

I have uploaded my WordPress website in cPanel. My plugins and all were working well until after a few months I logged in to update my website and its plugins. Now I can't install, remove, or modify plugins and my current WordPress account is in recovery mode. Please suggest some suggestion.

Comment: Try to login via FTP or the  cPanel Web-FTP and move or rename the "plugin" folder. See if you get access after this again. Reactivate one plugin at a time to see if the error will happen again and with which plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your site (apache2) error.log.

If you see access errors (can't mkdir, can't rmdir, permission denied), you may be dealing with a permissions problem.

the wp-content folder and it's children/subfolder need to be writable by the web server.

Usually (on an ubuntu-apache combination), this requires that you change ownership (via chown) for the whole directory tree to www-data:www-data.

On some systems (with php-strict mode) you will also need to change ownership (via chown) of the php-scripts that attempt the write.